# How to plot wavelength vs flux from ASCII file

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, ascii, spectrum

So I am attempting to plot a spectrum of a star from a local ASCII file (the path below in my program is the actual path, I just put a fake one here), but I get a tuple error.
I am pretty new to Python as you might be able to tell.

```
import numpy as np
import astrotools as at
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pyfits 
from astropy.io import fits


def pfit():
    f2 = open('/Users/myname/filepathtoASCIIfile', 'r') 
    lines = f2.readlines()
    f2.close()

    w = []
    f = []

    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            # if line.endswith('e-16') or line.endswith('e-15'):
            #     line = line[:-4]
            p = line.split()
            if not p[0].startswith('#'):
                try:
                    w.append(float(p[0]))
                    f.append(float(p[1]))
                except IndexError:
                    pass

    W = np.array(w)
    F = np.array(f)
    #return (W, F)

    plt.plot(W, F)
    plt.show()
```

The error I get when I run this into Python is:

```
     33 
---> 34     plt.plot(W, F)
     35     plt.show()
     36
```

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it may be that the error is elsewhere. There does not seem to be anything badly wrong with your code, and if you have been able to create arrays `W` and `F`, your data is quite ok.

The error hints that something sad has happened to `plt.plot`. You may have a line somewhere saying:

```
plt.plot = ...
```

for example, you have at some point written:

```
plt.plot = (W,F)
```

and this has overridden the original `plt.plot` function by a tuple. Now you try to call that tuple, and it does not work.

To verify if this is the case, add a line before your plotting command:

```
print plt.plot
```

The result should be something like:

```
<function plot at 0x10203040>
```

IF it is not, you have killed your `plot` command.

(BTW, thank you for showing the code and the actual error message! And welcome to SO!)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It turns out I actually just needed to quit python and restart. Nevertheless, since I would like to learn how to track down errors myself it was very useful to know I'd track this type of error by printing plt.plot... So thank you!